# Why do I only get values when I'm debugging, not executing?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

When running in Debug mode, I'm getting a response with the correct format, as below. I'm getting 60 values as I parsed:

[image]

But when I remove the breakpoints, I don't get the same things as when in debugging mode, as below:

[image: while in execution mode]

Have I missed something?

Comment: are you parsing JSON response with proper delegates

Comment: yes I am parsing JSON Response with Proper Delegate Methods.

Comment: So the issue is less results when breakpoints are not activated (in second you're not searching for 'title')? Is that the same request (same url and parameters)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to wait until the URL connection has completed before beginning to parse the data.